# JavaScript onclick handler not focusing or scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag, that when clicked, I want an input to get focus and the page to scroll to the form. Neither are happening and I have no idea why because it's so simple. Here is the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#RSVPForm" title="RSVP Now!" class="button">RSVP Now</a>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
const firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
const rsvpcta = document.querySelector("a[href*='#RSVPForm']");
rsvpcta.addEventListener("click", () => {firstname.focus();})
```

And it works in Safari, but in no other browser. I have no idea why it's not working anywhere else.
My test url is: https://meganandadam2018.com

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to reproduce?

Comment: @GMaiolo apologies...right when I posted the question, I realized I left out my test URL. Included now

Comment: @NoobieSatan Yes. My custom nav is working. My JS generated full year is working. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: remove firstname.focus(), it works fine , issue is with the .focus() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onclick event to anchor tag

```
<a onclick="focusfunc()">RSVP Now</a>
```

On clicking the link the focusfunc() function will be called.And add the focus() method as below:

```
function focusfunc(){
document.getElementById("firstname").focus();
}
```

Comment: Added appropriate code and pushed to test url. Still doesn't work on Android on Chrome or Mac in Chrome

Comment: @AdamMcGurk i have edited my answer by removing href from anchor tag.Please try this

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that's what the issue was. See the answer I posted above

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the problem was. I don't have to scroll to the element (through an href on the `a` tag) AND focus the element. Those two actions combined will cancel each other out, and that's what was happening. So I just got rid of the `href` and only had the firstname box focus on click and it all works perfectly now! So here's what the markup looks like:

```
<button type="button" title="RSVP Now!" id="rsvpcta">RSVP Now</button>
```

And here's the JS:

```
 const rsvpcta = document.getElementById("rsvpcta"),
 firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
rsvpcta.addEventListener("click", () => {firstname.focus();})
```